# Time difference is correct and incorrect at same time with same code, python time and date time module

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-requests

I am calculating the time differance between api and system time, the code is working correctly, but showing incorrect result.

```
url="Some url"

for sec in range(30):                                                              #30 times hitting
    time.sleep(1)                                                                  #time delay of 1 seconds, 30 hits ,2 sec so 60 second totally
    r = requests.get(url, params={}, headers = headers)                            # hitting the url after 2 seconds
    reqres = json.loads(r.text)
 time_in_api=reqres['last_updated_at_time']
    time_in_api=time.ctime(time_in_api/1000000)
    time_in_api_readable=datetime.datetime.strptime(str(time_in_api), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
    
    our_time=datetime.datetime.now()
    our_time = our_time.replace(microsecond=0)
    
    # calculation of time differance

    timediff=time_in_api_readable-our_time
    print(timediff,time_in_api_readable,our_time)
```

and the output is,

```
0:00:02 2021-05-20 21:04:34 2021-05-20 21:04:32
0:00:00 2021-05-20 21:04:34 2021-05-20 21:04:34
0:00:01 2021-05-20 21:04:38 2021-05-20 21:04:37
0:00:00 2021-05-20 21:04:39 2021-05-20 21:04:39
0:00:01 2021-05-20 21:04:42 2021-05-20 21:04:41
-1 day, 23:59:59 2021-05-20 21:04:42 2021-05-20 21:04:43
0:00:01 2021-05-20 21:04:47 2021-05-20 21:04:46
-1 day, 23:59:59 2021-05-20 21:04:47 2021-05-20 21:04:48
0:00:01 2021-05-20 21:04:52 2021-05-20 21:04:51
-1 day, 23:59:58 2021-05-20 21:04:52 2021-05-20 21:04:54
-1 day, 23:59:55 2021-05-20 21:04:52 2021-05-20 21:04:57
-1 day, 23:59:53 2021-05-20 21:04:52 2021-05-20 21:04:59
-1 day, 23:59:50 2021-05-20 21:04:52 2021-05-20 21:05:02
-1 day, 23:59:47 2021-05-20 21:04:52 2021-05-20 21:05:05
-1 day, 23:59:44 2021-05-20 21:04:52 2021-05-20 21:05:08
```

Comment: Seems like the right answer in an unintuitive form. The result of `21:04:52 - 21:05:02` on the same day could be phrased as `-1 day + 23:59:50`, which is essentially `-10 seconds`.

Comment: How to make this as only one form as of 0:00:01 bcz the time differance is showing differantly

Comment: And also the time differance is -1 day, 23.59.58 not -1day + 23.59.58 @kemp

Comment: or how to handle the time differance, as i want to take time differance more than 10 seconds. that one day and seconds format shows 86000 seconds as time differance

Comment: "the time differance is -1 day, 23.59.58 not -1day + 23.59.58". I wasn't telling you how it's written I was telling you how to interpret it. The fact that it's not written like that is why I said it's an unintuitive form (at least until you find out why it's written that way).

Comment: Thank you, found solution by using total seconds.. I didnt understand the unintuitive form at first glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an issue with human reading a "timedelta" object.
You may consider "total_seconds()" to solve your problem.

```
import datetime


TimeNow = datetime.datetime.now()
TimeNow = TimeNow.replace(microsecond = 0)

TimeTenSecondsFromNow = TimeNow + datetime.timedelta(seconds = 10)


print ('TimeNow', TimeNow)
print ('TimeTenSecondsFromNow', TimeTenSecondsFromNow)


TimeDiff = TimeNow - TimeTenSecondsFromNow
print ('TimeDiff', TimeDiff)


DiffTotalSeconds = TimeDiff.total_seconds()
print ('DiffTotalSeconds', DiffTotalSeconds)
```

Output:

```
>>> TimeNow 2021-05-20 12:43:26
>>> TimeTenSecondsFromNow 2021-05-20 12:43:36
>>> TimeDiff -1 day, 23:59:50
>>> DiffTotalSeconds -10.0
```

Comment: Solved my problem